# google places autocomplete accept only valid entry

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I have implimented Google's autocomplete api to an input on my website.
Is there a way to check\restrict the user to entring only a valid address?

For example I dont want to user entering an a string wich is not suggested to him by google's api.

Also I want the adress to be in the following format: Street HosueNum, City, Country, 
so if the user doesnt fill a house number or a country and so on...the result wont be accepted.

```
function googleAutoAddress(){
    var placeSearch, autocomplete;
    var componentForm = {
      street_number: "short_name",
      route: "long_name",
      locality: "long_name",
      administrative_area_level_1: "short_name",
      country: "long_name",
      postal_code: "short_name"
    };
      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
          /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById("ENaddress")),
          { types: ["geocode"] });
      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, "place_changed", function() {
        fillInAddress();
      });
    }

function fillInAddress() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = "";
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}
```